# insert delimiter in file using Linux script

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed

I have a non delimited text file consisting of around 1 million rows.

Sample rows

```
1YBL LOYALTY EXT 1000101172019001
2000100101000011512753184907301010614199100919699034659      VIDYA.SAGAR1@bank.IN                                     VIDYA SAGAR                             CROSS                                   BANDRA                                  WM                                      DELHI                         456471
3000000027
```

On each row starting with digit "2","1","3"(rowtype) I have to insert delimiter based on the count of characters i.e on the end  0-1, 1-20,21-25... so on

How to do this using Linux script ?

Desired Output

```
1|YBL LOYALTY EXT |10001|01172019|001
2|00010010100001151|2753|184907301010614199100919699034659      |VIDYA.SAGAR1@bank.IN                                     |VIDYA SAGAR                             |CROSS                                   |BANDRA                                  |WM                                      |DELHI                         |456471
3|000000027
```

I tried this command

```
perl -ne ' if(/^2/) { @x=(1,19,6,4,3,8,20,60,40,40,40,40,30); $i=0;
       while($i<=$#x) { $s=$x[$i]; $_=~s/(.{$s})/printf("%s|",$1);""/e;$i++ } 
       print "$_"}   if(/^1/) { @x=(1,16,5,8); $i=0;
       while($i<=$#x) { $s=$x[$i]; $_=~s/(.{$s})/printf("%s|",$1);""/e;$i++ } 
       print "$_" }  if(/^3/) { @x=(1); $i=0;
       while($i<=$#x) { $s=$x[$i]; $_=~s/(.{$s})/printf("%s|",$1);""/e;$i++ } 
       print "$_" }'  filename`
```

INPUT ROWS

```
1YBL LOYALTY EXT 1000112102018001
2000100101000002631653184911501010111199100919323739251      VIJAYPANDEY1191@GMAIL.COM                                   VIJAY PANDEY                            PART OF GROUND FLOOR & BASEMENT         SHOPPER STOP SV ROAD ANDHERI WEST       LANDMARK-ERSTWHILE CRASSWORD BOOK STORE MUMBAI                        400058
2000100101000019920453184964321010513199000919878857482      MAKSUDMASTER7775@GMAIL.COM                                  MOHAMAD MAQSHUD MASTER                  H COLLECTION NEW SHIVPURI               GALI NO 1                               NEAR MAKHAN SINGH CHOWK                 LUDHIANA                      141008
2000100101000023500853184923441010913197300919375580888      JAYNTITALA@GMAIL.COM                                        JAYANTIBHAI TADA                        44 KHODIYAR NAGAR B S ABHISHEK          SUDAMA CHOWK                            KHODIYARNAGAR MOTA VARACHHA             SURAT                         395006
3000000066
```

EXPECTED OUTPUT

```
1|YBL LOYALTY EXT |10001|12102018|001
2|0001001010000026316|531849|1150|101|01111991|00919323739251      |VIJAYPANDEY1191@GMAIL.COM                                   |VIJAY PANDEY                            |PART OF GROUND FLOOR & BASEMENT         |SHOPPER STOP SV ROAD ANDHERI WEST       |LANDMARK-ERSTWHILE CRASSWORD BOOK STORE |MUMBAI                        |400058
2|0001001010000199204|531849|6432|101|05131990|00919878857482      |MAKSUDMASTER7775@GMAIL.COM                                  |MOHAMAD MAQSHUD MASTER                  |H COLLECTION NEW SHIVPURI               |GALI NO 1                               |NEAR MAKHAN SINGH CHOWK                 |LUDHIANA                      |141008
2|0001001010000235008|531849|2344|101|09131973|00919375580888      |JAYNTITALA@GMAIL.COM                                        |JAYANTIBHAI TADA                        |44 KHODIYAR NAGAR B S ABHISHEK          |SUDAMA CHOWK                            |KHODIYARNAGAR MOTA VARACHHA             |SURAT                         |395006
3|000000066
```

GETTING THIS BUT

```
1|YBL LOYALTY EXT |10001|12102018|001
2|0001001010000026316|531849|1150|101|01111991|00919323739251      |VIJAYPANDEY1191@GMAIL.COM                                   |VIJAY PANDEY                            |PART OF GROUND FLOOR & BASEMENT         |SHOPPER STOP SV ROAD ANDHERI WEST       |LANDMARK-ERSTWHILE CRASSWORD BOOK STORE |MUMBAI                        |400058
2|0001001010000199204|531849|6432|101|05131990|00919878857482      |MAKSUDMASTER7775@GMAIL.COM                                  |MOHAMAD MAQSHUD MASTER                  |H COLLECTION NEW SHIVPURI               |GALI NO 1                               |NEAR MAKHAN SINGH CHOWK                 |LUDHIANA                      |141008
1|41008|
2|0001001010000235008|531849|2344|101|09131973|00919375580888      |JAYNTITALA@GMAIL.COM                                        |JAYANTIBHAI TADA                        |44 KHODIYAR NAGAR B S ABHISHEK          |SUDAMA CHOWK                            |KHODIYARNAGAR MOTA VARACHHA             |SURAT                         |395006
3|95006
3|000000066
```

Comment: Does the email address need to change also?

Comment: @JamesBrown no need to change

Comment: @muddassir-rahman Then you should correct the desired output.

Comment: @Pino Thanx , i changed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try Perl as well

```
perl -lpe ' if(/^2/) { @x=(1,17,4); 
           for $i (@x) { s/(.{$i})//; printf("%s|",$1) } }' input_file
```

with the given inputs

```
$ cat rahman.txt
1YBL LOYALTY EXT 1000101172019001
2000100101000011512753184907301010614199100919699034659      VIDYA.SAGAR1@bank.IN                                     VIDYA SAGAR                             CROSS                                   BANDRA                                  WM                                      DELHI                         456471
3000000027

$ perl -lpe ' if(/^2/) { @x=(1,17,4); 
             for $i (@x) { s/(.{$i})//; printf("%s|",$1) } }' rahman.txt
1YBL LOYALTY EXT 1000101172019001
2|00010010100001151|2753|184907301010614199100919699034659      VIDYA.SAGAR1@bank.IN                                     VIDYA SAGAR                             CROSS                                   BANDRA                                  WM                                      DELHI                         456471
3000000027

$
```

just add entries to @x=(1,17,4) .. @x=(1,17,4,10,20)

***EDIT1:***

To add delimiters for those fields which can be split by space, use the below

```
$ perl -lpe ' if(/^2/) { @x=(1,17,4); 
             for $i (@x) { s/(.{$i})//; printf("%s|",$1) } s/\S+\s+\K/|/g }' rahman.txt
1YBL LOYALTY EXT 1000101172019001
2|00010010100001151|2753|184907301010614199100919699034659      |VIDYA.SAGAR1@bank.IN                                     |VIDYA |SAGAR                             |CROSS                                   |BANDRA                                  |WM                                      |DELHI                         |456471
3000000027

$
```

***Explanation to the code***

```
Explanation
perl -lpe   # use -p for printing by default at the end of perl one-liner
        # this makes sure when you dont have a line starting with 2 the line is printed after the if statement.

' if(/^2/)  # if - select line that starts with 2. $_ will have the current line
{ 
@x=(1,17,4); # x is an array to hold the widths of fields. - 1, 17, 4 
for $i (@x)  # open for loop to loop through the array x
{ 
s/(.{$i})//;  # no variable is specified, so the substitution acts on the $_ i.e current line
          # first instance is s/(.{1})// => match one character and store it in $1 capturing variable
          # replace the captured part with nothing and update $_
          # e.g if the line is "200010010100001151" .. loop one will capture "2" and $_ becomes "00010010100001151"
          # loop 2 => s/(.{17})// matches 17 character and $1 stores "00010010100001151"
printf("%s|",$1)  # print $1 along with delimiter pipe 
}  # end of for loop
}  # end of if
# here is default print statement in perl that will print the $_ after all modification
' input_file
```

EDIT2

I get below results based on your inputs. It works correctly.. what issues you see?

```
$ perl -ne ' if(/^2/) { @x=(1,19,6,4,3,8,20,60,40,40,40,40,30); $i=0;
>        while($i<=$#x) { $s=$x[$i]; $_=~s/(.{$s})/printf("%s|",$1);""/e;$i++ }
>        print "$_"}   if(/^1/) { @x=(1,16,5,8); $i=0;
>        while($i<=$#x) { $s=$x[$i]; $_=~s/(.{$s})/printf("%s|",$1);""/e;$i++ }
>        print "$_" }  if(/^3/) { @x=(1); $i=0;
>        while($i<=$#x) { $s=$x[$i]; $_=~s/(.{$s})/printf("%s|",$1);""/e;$i++ }
>        print "$_" }'  rahman.txt
1|YBL LOYALTY EXT |10001|01172019|001
2|0001001010000115127|531849|0730|101|06141991|00919699034659      |VIDYA.SAGAR1@bank.IN                                     VID|YA SAGAR                             CRO|SS                                   BAN|DRA                                  WM |                                     DEL|HI                         456|471
3|000000027

$
```

EDIT3:

Got the issue... $_ is modified and so at the end of /^2/ if loop, the $_ holds the value of "141008", which is then satisfying the next if (/^1/) condition and that if also executes.. To avoid it, just copy the $_ to a $line variable in the beginning and just check $line against /^2/, /^3/, /^1/ in the separate if loops.

```
$ perl -lne '$line=$_; if($line=~/^2/) { @x=(1,19,6,4,3,8,20,60,40,40,40,40,30); $i=0;
       while($i<=$#x) { $s=$x[$i]; $_=~s/(.{$s})/printf("%s|",$1);""/e;$i++ }
        print "$_" }
       if($line=~/^1/) { @x=(1,16,5,8); $i=0;
       while($i<=$#x) { $s=$x[$i]; $_=~s/(.{$s})/printf("%s|",$1);""/e;$i++ }
        print "$_" }
       if($line=~/^3/) { @x=(1); $i=0;
       while($i<=$#x) { $s=$x[$i]; $_=~s/(.{$s})/printf("%s|",$1);""/e;$i++ }
       print "$_" }'  rahman2.txt
1|YBL LOYALTY EXT |10001|12102018|001
2|0001001010000026316|531849|1150|101|01111991|00919323739251      |VIJAYPANDEY1191@GMAIL.COM                                   |VIJAY PANDEY                            |PART OF GROUND FLOOR & BASEMENT         |SHOPPER STOP SV ROAD ANDHERI WEST       |LANDMARK-ERSTWHILE CRASSWORD BOOK STORE |MUMBAI                        |400058
2|0001001010000199204|531849|6432|101|05131990|00919878857482      |MAKSUDMASTER7775@GMAIL.COM                                  |MOHAMAD MAQSHUD MASTER                  |H COLLECTION NEW SHIVPURI               |GALI NO 1                               |NEAR MAKHAN SINGH CHOWK                 |LUDHIANA                      |141008
2|0001001010000235008|531849|2344|101|09131973|00919375580888      |JAYNTITALA@GMAIL.COM                                        |JAYANTIBHAI TADA                        |44 KHODIYAR NAGAR B S ABHISHEK          |SUDAMA CHOWK                            |KHODIYARNAGAR MOTA VARACHHA             |SURAT                         |395006
3|000000066

$
```

Comment: you have not taken file as input ?

Comment: updated.. it is at the end of the command.. just have a look at the sample run section.. I have given rahman.txt

Comment: @MuddassirRahman just curious: what led you to accept an answer using a tool you didn't ask for that doesn't produce the output you asked for?

Comment: @EdMorton (1) "_tool you didn't ask for_" -- happens all the time, specially with this set of languages; (2) "_doesn't produce the output you asked for_" -- question is rather unclear; also, this has been added (trivially) to the answer.

Comment: @EdMorton But I got curious -- seriously, questioning why they accept what they do?  They accept whatever they goddamn want; that's the deal. And asking that right under the accepted answer strikes me as not very nice to the person who honestly just answered here.

Comment: @zdim - sorry your sensibilities are offended. The OP can accept whatever answer they want but I'm not seeing why it's a problem for you if someone asks why they accepted the answer they did and when asking a question in a comment related to a specific answer, putting that comment under the answer you're asking about is the normal thing done on the site. The question was perfectly clear on  the desired output, the given answer didn't provide that output and, less importantly, was using a tool the OP hadn't tagged when they asked the question so I asked why - doesn't seem outrageous to do so.

Comment: @EdMorton Well, never mind my sensibilities (I have to stash that away very often here anyway); it's not about that.  The fact is that one can legitimately ask that at the _very_ least on one or two out of ten pages here -- but people practically never do, and there are good reasons for that.  That question is off limits since the choice is strictly and solely the asker's; nobody else's business. Anything other would cause no end to strong arming people to accept this or that.

Comment: @EdMorton Here, your code comment is spot on and helpful for all, and it got addressed. (The choice of the tool, less illuminating honestly, but surely legit.)  But with a question "hey why did you accept this" -- it comes across as a little demeaning (what I don't think you meant!), and it factually is a form of pressure on the OP (what I am certain you didn't mean!).

Comment: @EdMorton actually `FIELDWIDTHS` was giving error. so I didn't go for your answer

Comment: @stack0114106 can you please explain your answer little bit

Comment: @stack0114106 actually i need to add delimiter to rows starting with 1 and 3 also. I modified your answer , it worked but with some errors

Comment: I'm working on adding the explanation.. use /^[23]/ for matching with 3 also in the if condition...

Comment: Added explanation.. pls check and paste the error that you face..

Comment: @MuddassirRahman I didn't ask why you didn't accept my answer, I asked why you accepted this answer for the reasons I stated in that comment. Whatever - it really doesn't matter I was just curious like I said but certainly not curious enough to drag out the discussion this long

Comment: @stack0114106 Please check my edits

Comment: look like it works correctly.. check my EDIT2

Comment: @stack0114106 it worked for single row, but in case of multiple rows it didn't work , Please check my edits

Comment: pls check my EDIT3...

Answer (score 4):

With GNU awk for FIELDWIDTHS:

```
$ awk -v FIELDWIDTHS='1 17 4 *' -v OFS='|' '/^2/{$1=$1; gsub(/\s+/,"&"OFS)} 1' file
1YBL LOYALTY EXT 1000101172019001
2|00010010100001151|2753|184907301010614199100919699034659      |VIDYA.SAGAR1@bank.IN                                     |VIDYA |SAGAR                             |CROSS                                   |BANDRA                                  |WM                                      |DELHI                         |456471
3000000027
```

The above use of FIELDWIDTHS says the input should be treated as separated into 4 fields of width 1 char, 17 chars, 4 chars and then the rest.

When you assign a value to a field awk recompiles the record replacing the input field separators with the value of OFS so $1=$1 is causing `|`s to be inserted between each of the fields described by FIELDWIDTHS.

Once that's done there's still all the remaining space-separated text to get a field separator added so the gsub() appends an OFS after every series of spaces.

Older versions of gawk don't support `*` as meaning `the rest of the line` - if you have that situation then just replace `*` with a large value like `99999`.

Comment: Could you explain a bit your answer. I really would like to understand, but solutions with awk are always tricky to me ;) Thank's

Comment: @jumpy OK I added an explanation.

Comment: thank you, I better understand how you add the `|` on the rest of the line.

Comment: @EdMorton getting error `invalid FIELDWIDTHS value, near `*' `

Comment: Then you're using an older version of gawk that doesn't support `*` as meaning `the rest of the line`. Change `*` to some large value like `9999`.

Answer (score 0):

You do have delimiters in your file, you just don't see them: it's the space/tab characters. So you just need to replace those, using the `sed/xxx/|/g` command (by `xxx` I mean the space or TAB characters). In case you doubt whether your characters are spaces or tabs, you might open your file in a hex editor (space is ASCII code 32 (Hex : 20) and TAB has 9 (Hex : 09)).

Comment: That won't change `20` into `2|0`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with gnu sed :

```
sed -E '/^2/{s//&|/;s/(.{19})(....)(\S+\s+)/\1|\2|\3|/}' infile
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you don't have `FIELDSWIDTHS` then try following.

```
awk -v var="1,18,4" -v OFS="|" '
BEGIN{
  num=split(var,array,",")
}
{
  for(i=1;i<=num;i++){
     val=val?(i==num?val substr($0,array[i-1]+1,array[i]):val substr($0,array[i-1]+1,array[i]) OFS):substr($0,1,array[i]) OFS
     sum+=array[i]
  }
  if(sum==length($0)){
    print val
  }
  else{
    rest=substr($0,sum)
    gsub(/[[:space:]]+/,"&"OFS,rest)
    print val,rest
  }
    sum=rest=val=""
}
'   Input_file
```

Comment: @Muddassir Rahman, could you please check once this one, if this helps you too?